# Отступ сверху дива

Tags: html, css

образовался отступ сверху. Как его убрать?

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
  body {
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас только css в задании, добавьте html, а то ничего не понятно. Используете бутстрап?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена

```css
  body {;
    margin: -2em;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  }
```